# Java one file to anothe file appending

Tags: java, arrays, list, append

I have two data file Test1 and Test2.

Test1 datas:

```
1.0  2.0  3.0
2.0  4.0  5.0
3.0  1.0  2.0
4.0  9.0  2.0
7.0  0.0  0.0
8.0  7.0  1.0
10.0 2.0  5.0
11.0 0.0  0.0
13.0 1.0  1.0
15.0 1.0  1.0
17.0 2.0  2.0
```

Test2.txt

```
 5.0   2.0   5.0   6.0
 6.0   1.0   2.0   9.0
 9.0   0.0   1.0   3.0
 12.0  0.0   0.0   0.0
 14.0  1.0   1.0   1.0
```

test4.txt(Output file)

```
 1.0  2.0  3.0
 2.0  4.0  5.0
 3.0  1.0  2.0
 4.0  9.0  2.0
 5.0   2.0   5.0   6.0
 6.0   1.0   2.0   9.0
 7.0  0.0  0.0
 8.0  7.0  1.0
 9.0   0.0   1.0   3.0
 10.0 2.0  5.0
 11.0 0.0  0.0
 12.0  0.0   0.0   0.0
 13.0 1.0  1.0
 14.0  1.0   1.0   1.0
 15.0 1.0  1.0
 17.0 2.0  2.0
```

My code:

```
public class Insertelementfile {
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
    Scanner X=new Scanner(new File("c:\\test1.txt"));
    Scanner Y=new Scanner(new File("C:\\test2.txt"));
    PrintWriter write1=null;
     write1= new PrintWriter(new File("C:\\test4.txt"));
    double a=0.0,d=0.0;
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    List<Double> list1=new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double>list2=new ArrayList<>();
    double[]arrX=new double[11];
    double[]arrY=new double[5];
    double[] s = new double[16];
    while(X.hasNext()){
        a = X.nextDouble();
        list1.add(a);
        double b=X.nextDouble();
        double c=X.nextDouble();
    }
    while(Y.hasNext()) {
        d = Y.nextDouble();
        list2.add(d);
        double e=Y.nextDouble();
        double f=Y.nextDouble();
        double g=Y.nextDouble();
    }
    for(int i1=0;i1<list1.size();i1++) {

        arrX[i1]=list1.get(i1);
    }

    for(int j1=0;j1<list2.size();j1++){
        arrY[j1]=list2.get(j1);
    }
    while(i<arrX.length && j<arrY.length){
        if (arrX[i] < arrY[j]){
            s[k]=arrX[i];
            i++;
        }
        else{
            s[k] = arrY[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    // Copy the remaining elements in arrX to s
    if (i < arrX.length) {
        // arraycopy(source, sourcepos, dest, destpos, numOfElements)
        System.arraycopy(arrX, i, s, k, (arrX.length - i));
    }


    // Copy the remaining elements in arrY to s
    if (j < arrY.length) {
        // arraycopy(source, sourcepos, dest, destpos, numOfElements)
        System.arraycopy(arrY, j, s, k, (arrY.length - j));
    }
    System.out.println( Arrays.toString(s));
    write1.write(Arrays.toString(s));
    write1.flush();
    write1.close();
}
}
```

The output I get is something like that:
  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 17.0]
  But the remaining columns are not there in my output. I take the 1st Columns of both file as my key attribute and insert element depending upon there ordering. What should I do to get my desire output?

Comment: In your first for loop, you're reading in the second and third values for a line, but you're not storing them anywhere, they're simply not getting used. Also, I highly highly recommend naming your variables better. For example, instead of "b", "test1SecondValue" makes it much easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: Also, instead of manually translating an ArrayList to an array with a loop, you can simply call arraylist.toArray(<array of the type you want>).

Comment: How could I get my desired output?The output that I get is a part of whole output.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class to keep your data in. Something like:

```
public class MyData implements Comparable<MyData>{
    public ArrayList<Double> data;

    public MyData(){
        data = new ArrayList<Double>();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyData otherData) {
        if(otherData == null){
            return 1;
        }
        if(data.size() != 0 && otherData.data.size() != 0){
            if(otherData.data.get(0) >= data.get(0)){
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

You can then keep an ArrayList, reading one lines values into one MyData object. You could then use Collections.sort(that arraylist) to sort it, and then iterate over it and print it to your file.

Comment: Use that MyData class to store your lines. When you loop with the scanner, add a MyData to an array list, then add the doubles you get from the scanner to the arraylist in the MyData. This way, you have all the information for the line kept together. In addition, you can sort it easily with Collections.sort, meaning that you can sort it and then just loop over the list writing it to a file. What specific parts are you having trouble understanding? I'm happy to help, but I can't help if I don't know what you're having trouble with.

Comment: I don't need to sort. The data are already sorted.But there are some gap between data like 5 is missing after 4 from test1. We have to fulfill those gaps only. The code you write down that is not clear.What is data? what is other data? How could I link this code with my code? Can you please modify my code so that it is easy for me to understand.